# jquery prepend adds an unwanted space

Tags: jquery

I want to add a div to another div after a form submit with Ajax.

It works but , for no reason, prepend() add a whitespace after the declaration of a span.

I'm using this code (sorry a bit long):

```
$('#list_tweet').prepend('<div class="tweet" data-idtweet="' + data.id +         '"><div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle pull-right" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">    ...</button><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"><li><a href="#" data-idtweet="' + data.id +'"  title="Effacer ce tweet"  class="deletetweet" onclick="return false;">Effacer ce tweet</a></li></ul></div><img src="/instatux/img/' + data.avatar_session + '"alt="image utilisateur" class="img-circle vcenter"/><a href="/instatux/' + data.auth_name +'" class="link_username_tweet">' + data.auth_name + '</a><span class="alias_tweet">@' + data.auth_name +'</span> - A l\'instant<p>' + data.contenu_tweet +'</p><span class="nb_like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="vertical-align:center></span><span id="compteur_like-' + data.id + '">0</span></span><span class="nb_comm_share">0 commentaire(s) - 0 partage(s)</span><br /><br /><span class="link_comm_share"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="vertical-align:center"></span> <a href="#" data-value="'+data.id+'" class="link_like" onclick="return false;">J&#039;aime</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="vertical-align:center"></span>&nbsp;<a href="/instatux/post/'+data.id+'">Commenter</a></span></div>');
```

The problem is `<span id="compteur_like-' + data.id + '">0</span>`, when i look the source code there is a whitespace before compteur_like and i need to access to this element after.

How can i avoid this ?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to see the output. Are you sure it's not the value of `data.id` that has the prefixed space?

Comment: Share your output.

Comment: Hello guys and thanks for your reply, i finally found my error  : i missed a " at the end of style="vertical-align:center>